# What questions should get the HCI tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [hci](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hci) tag has been applied very rarely, almost certainly less often than relevant. What sort of questions should have this tag? My inclination is anything approaching usability/UX work from a *scientific* perspective is a likely candidate for this tag.

Generalizing it too much would risk making it apply to most everything on the site, so I think we should have a more formal process for determining what does/doesn't get the tag and toss that in the tag's description.

Comment: I also have a hidden motive to find more objectively answerable HCI questions I can poach to ask on [cogsci.se] but I'd really love to see our site better organized for research based questinos too

Comment: Maybe I've got my definitions wrong, but I always saw HCI as focused more heavily towards interactions with the hardware rather than the software.

Comment: @dhmholley nah, HCI does software too, I wouldn't call it more focused on hardware at all.

Answer (score -1):

I think "formal process" is a scary phrase we should stay as far away from as possible for as long as we can.

The thing with UX is that it's so broad and so vague that often we find many similar terms that pretty much describe the same thing. Perhaps we should treat it more as a synonym than as its own thing. People searching for HCI on Google might intend to find questions that we happen to have labeled with interaction-design or something. I'd prefer for those people to find that kind of content than for us to become super-anal about which questions get which tags.

Comment: People won't find it as a keyword because it's not used, except on very rare questions and in the FAQ. There's no relevant tag to synonymize it to, especially not if we were to assume it covers everything on the site.

Comment: That's why I said "perhaps we should treat it as a synonym" - implying that we should modify it to work that way so that it has value for people searching (which it obviously doesn't right now)